# Superagent cannot set content type to ocsp-request

Tags: node.js, superagent, ocsp

I have a superagent, and I'm trying to set the content type.

```
return superagent.post(url)
.send(request)
.type('application/ocsp-request')
.end(function(err, res) {
 });
```

However, I keep getting this crash where it says

TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer

I was wondering if anyone had any idea.

When I remove the type field, then it passes.

Comment: Is there a particular url/request/host we can use?

Comment: Oh, I get the bug even when I remove host. I should remove it from the post

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the answer was I need to pass JSON.stringify(request) instead of just request.